# make with vim using Intel Fortran

Tags: vim, makefile, fortran, debian

I have a project with Fortran and I use gvim as my editor. When I use gfortran as my compiler in my makefile, I encounter no problems. I also have a version of the makefile that uses intel fortran and that makefile also works fine when called from the terminal.

My problem is within gvim. Gfortran version of my makefile works great when called within vim with :make and it shows me the errors and jumps to them etc. However, when I use the ifort version, :make command in vim gives me an error saying he could not find ifort.

ifort works fine from the terminal. I have both ~/.bashrc and /etc/bash.bashrc edited so that it sources intel compilers. I use Crunchbang Waldorf (read: Debian Testing) and I remember having the same problem in LMDE.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Vim runs the make command using the shell specified by the `shell` option.  By default, it does not start in interactive mode and thus does not read the `.bashrc` file.  Try adding the command line switch to make the shell interactive: `:set shell+=\ -i`, then use the `:make` command as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Move PATH modifications from `.bashrc`/`/etc/bash/bashrc` to `.profile`/`/etc/profile`. This way you won’t need interactive shell like @ib. suggests (and, by the way, you need to do modifications to only one file, not both).

If your distribution uses `/etc/env.d` it may make sense to do

```
echo 'PATH=/path/to/ifc/binaries' >> /etc/env.d/99ifort
env-update
```

. But this should be distribution-specific.